# How to send Contacts from iphone to MFI device using bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, ios6, bluetooth, mfi

How would I sync the `contacts` to `MFi` device so that it can be displayed on the device using `Phone Book Access Profile (PBAP)`.I am able to get the contacts from `address book`. I would like to know is there any alternative to this? How to initiate Phone book request from the device and how do I transfer it to `MFi` device.Please let me know any examples to sync the contacts using Bluetooth or any pointers to accomplish the task.'MFi' device supports `Serial Port Profile (SPP)`. I would like to sync the contacts in the delegate method mentioned below, but I am not sure how to start this. Any pointers to accomplish this.

`- (void)accessoryDidDisconnect:(EAAccessory *)accessory`

Comment: Bluetooth LE devices are not standard, MFi Bluetooth devices. Which of the two are you working with here? In either case, you're going to have to create a custom protocol on your Bluetooth or Bluetooth LE device that can receive contact information. Once you have that written, you'll know what you need to send to your device from an iOS application. This isn't really something we can do for you.

Answer (score 1):

what kind of bluetooth device? If you are making your own it must be Bluetooth 4.0. Low Energy. Then you can transfer any data using Core Bluetooth.

You must then define your own Service UUID, your own Characteristic UUID.
Search for devices (with your Service UUID for instance or 'nil' for all)
Connect
Find Services
Find Characteristics for each service

Now you can use GATT profile access to transfer data in whatever format you want. It can be the data from the phonebook if your bluetooth low energy device know how to decode that. Maybe you want to make your own format...

If you don't want to do this then you must join the MFI program to get the documentation.

Also you should really go to iTunes, then find the WWDC 2012 Session Videos. There are several which can explain stuff for you.
Session 701 is great about IOS Accessories
Session 703 about Core Bluetooth
Session 705 about Advanced Core Bluetooth

BR
Henrik

Comment: *"If you are making your own it must be Bluetooth 4.0. Low Energy."* - This is not true, that's one of the reasons why the MFi program exists.